# ObjC error throwing function returning () instead of BOOL

Tags: objective-c, error-handling, try-catch, return-value, swift2

I have an Objective C function declared as:

```
+ (BOOL)isScanningUnsupported:(NSError **)error;
```

and if it returns true, I have to return nil in the function i am calling it from (Swift).

So I call if like this:

```
 var isUnsupported = false

 do { try  isUnsupported = PPCoordinator.isScanningUnsupported()
 } catch let error { throw error }

 if isUnsupported {return nil }
```

But it tells me:

> Cannot assign a value of type '()' to a value of type 'Bool'

In Objective C it was called like:

```
if ([PPCoordinator isScanningUnsupported:error]) {
    return nil;
}
```

what can I do????

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are describing the standard way that functions that produce an error in Objective-C are interpreted in Swift. Methods in Objective-C that take a pointer to an error and return BOOL are assumed to be void and throw in Swift by default.

This is because that is almost always what it means in Objective-C. i.e. true means "ran successfully", false means "failed and I put the error in the pointer you supplied".

Your method doesn't conform to normal Objective-C conventions so you could try disabling Swift's conversion to a throwing function with the `NS_SWIFT_NOTHROW` macro on the declaration of PPCoordinator.isScanningUnsupported.

Comment: Returning `false` does not always mean a failure. It can be a valid value too. E.g. `checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError` returns Bool in Swift.

Comment: @pointum As I said: "almost always". Interestingly, the [online documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSURL/checkResourceIsReachableAndReturnError:) has an error in it. It claims the Swift function returns Bool but also has the standard paragraph about error handling in Swift (incorrectly, in this case).

Answer (score 1):

I think you want:

```
var isUnsupported = false

 do { try  PPCoordinator.isScanningUnsupported()
    isUnsupported = true 
 } catch let error {
    throw error // or do nothing?
 }

 if isUnsupported {return nil }
```

If you look at the Swift definition of your function, I would expect no return value (i.e. void).

Answer (score 0):

this is working now for me:

```
    if let _ = try? PPCoordinator.isScanningUnsupported() { return nil }
```